# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint PK_Casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to add a new data base through a script, but getting some errors, already tried to let out the double fields, but that didn't work for me.

```
USE master
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE NAME = 'MijnFilms')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE MijnFilms SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    DROP DATABASE MijnFilms
END
GO

-- Creatie databank Bibliotheek
CREATE DATABASE MijnFilms
GO

USE MijnFilms
GO

--Creatie tabel AUTEUR   
CREATE TABLE ACTEUR
(
    Acteur_id int NOT NULL,
    ActeurNaam nvarchar(40),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Acteur PRIMARY KEY(acteur_id)
) 
GO

--Creatie tabel CATEGORIE  
CREATE TABLE CASTING 
(
    Film_id int NOT NULL,
    Acteur_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Casting PRIMARY KEY(Film_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK1_Casting FOREIGN KEY(Acteur_id) REFERENCES Acteur(acteur_id)
) 
GO

--Creatie tabel BOEKEN   
CREATE TABLE FILM
(
    Film_id int NOT NULL,
    Titel nvarchar(40),
    Jaar smallint,
    Score int,
    Stemmen int,
    CONSTRAINT FK1_Film FOREIGN KEY(Film_id) REFERENCES Casting(film_id),
) 
GO

--Opvullen van de tabellen met testdata 
INSERT INTO ACTEUR(Acteur_id, ActeurNaam) VALUES (1, 'Tom Hanks')
INSERT INTO ACTEUR(Acteur_id, ActeurNaam) VALUES (2, 'Helen Hunt')
INSERT INTO ACTEUR(Acteur_id, ActeurNaam) VALUES (3, 'Catherine Zeta Jones')
GO

INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (2, 3)
GO

INSERT INTO FILM(Film_id, Titel, jaar, Score, Stemmen) VALUES (1, 'Cast Away', 2000, 75,1)
INSERT INTO FILM(Film_id, Titel, jaar, Score, Stemmen) VALUES (2, 'The Terminal', 2004, 62,1)
GO
```

Right now, I get an error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 60
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Casting'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CASTING'. The duplicate key value is (2).

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. `Film_id` is a primary key in `CASTING`, yet you try to `INSERT` the values `1` and `2` twice; thus the second attempt to insert `1` for `film_id` results in a duplicate key.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're trying to insert a `film_id` of `1` (and `2`) into `casting` twice but primary keys need to be unique.

You could use a composite primary key here, consisting of the film's and the actor's ID.

Also the film's ID should be the primary key in `film` and a foreign key in `casting` not the other way round. That requires `film` to be created before `casting` though. That also applies for the `INSERT`s -- `film` has to come before `casting`.

```
...
CREATE TABLE film
             (film_id integer
                      NOT NULL,
              titel nvarchar(40),
              jaar smallint,
              score integer,
              stemmen integer,
              CONSTRAINT pk_film
                         PRIMARY KEY (film_id));

CREATE TABLE acteur
             (acteur_id integer
                        NOT NULL,
              acteurnaam nvarchar(40),
              CONSTRAINT pk_acteur
                         PRIMARY KEY (acteur_id));

CREATE TABLE casting
             (film_id integer
                      NOT NULL,
              acteur_id integer
                        NOT NULL,
              CONSTRAINT pk_casting
                         PRIMARY KEY (film_id,
                                      acteur_id),
              CONSTRAINT fk1_casting
                         FOREIGN KEY (film_id)
                                     REFERENCES film
                                                (film_id),
              CONSTRAINT fk2_casting
                         FOREIGN KEY (acteur_id)
                                     REFERENCES acteur
                                                (acteur_id));
...

INSERT INTO film ...

INSERT INTO acteur ...

INSERT INTO casting ...
```

Answer (score -2):

You are creating the table with constraints

```
CREATE TABLE CASTING 
(
    Film_id int NOT NULL,
    Acteur_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Casting PRIMARY KEY(Film_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK1_Casting FOREIGN KEY(Acteur_id) REFERENCES Acteur(acteur_id)
) 
GO
```

and then you are inserting duplicated records in the table

```
INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO CASTING (Film_id, Acteur_id) VALUES (2, 3)
```

You need to remove the constraint or you need to make COMPOSITE KEY by creating the key on `FILM_ID` and `ACTEUR_ID`